# CSS vw and percentage value convert to pixel value

Tags: less

How do we know that how many pixels in `width:100%`  and `width:100vw` ?

**Situation**

```
body{
 width:100%;
}
.container{
  width:1000px;
}
```

How do i get exact value ?

```
balanceWidth = bodywidth - containerwidth
```

*I know about css calc `width: calc(100% - 1000px);`*  ,  I need to get exact pixel value

Comment: You don't be able to know how many pixels are a percent value in CSS. You need to use javascript or some javascript libraries like jQuery

Comment: The question I'm asking is **why do you need the exact pixel value?** Either you want percentage / viewport responsiveness or you don't.

Comment: Are you using Sass or LESS?  You have to pick one or the other, otherwise your question could potentially be interpreted as a software request (eg. which language supports X?)

Answer (score 1):

For this:

```
balanceWidth = bodywidth - containerwidth
```

You can use calc method:

```
width: calc(100% - 1000px);
```

When you have 1000px wide element you assume the percentage wide is 100% and for 1% you can calculate taking 1000px dividing by 100.

Comment: From your edit, you need scripting language like jquery.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you width of container is 1000px and you css vw value is `10vw` it means `10%` of your container width it is very similar to using `10%`.

So taking example of `10vw` it means `10%`.

Reference : https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/